# Editing CSS file with a PHP Regex

Tags: php, css, regex, file, minify

I need to edit my css "string" and add #holder selector before every single selector. For example;

I want to change this css string;

```
/* the css file with comments */ 
.header ul, .footer #div, .selector3 a
{
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

.selector4, .selector5 ul > li, .selector6 a:hover
{
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    -moz-text-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
}
```

as

```
/* the css file with comments */ 
#holder .header ul, #holder .footer #div, #holder .selector3 a
{
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

#holder .selector4, #holder .selector5 ul > li, #holder .selector6 a:hover
{
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    -moz-text-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
}
```

I have used this regex to minify the string and it works fine so you can just ignore the comment lines.

```
preg_replace('@({)\s+|(\;)\s+|/\*.+?\*\/|\R@is', '$1$2 ', $css);
```

I'm searching a regex method to do it but any other solution also would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to replace *every* class selector? Or only a select few known ones?

Comment: there are many diff. selectors in my css and i have to customize the code for specific part of the page such as #holder. So the answer is yes i need to replace every selector.

Comment: That's going to be very difficult to do as **one** regex.

Comment: try http://lesscss.org/

Comment: or this http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: @Mathew Foscarini unfortunately it is not an option in my case. I'll put a special character to define the selector lines than use explode, foreach, replace etc. It'll need some more lines than i thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$pat = '~(?>/\*(?>[^*]++|\*(?!/))*+\*/|{[^}]*+})(*SKIP)(?!)|[^\s,{/][^,{/]++~';
$css = preg_replace($pat, '#holder $0', $css);
```

The idea is to avoid comments and content inside curly brackets, then you can easily find all selectors with `[^\s,{/][^,{/]++`.

To do that you put in a group the subpatterns for comments (i.e. `/\*(?>[^*]++|\*(?!/))*+\*/`) and for content inside curly brackets (i.e. `{[^}]*+}`), then you force the pattern to fail and forbid backtracking in the matched substrings.

`(*SKIP)(?!)` is used for that. `(*SKIP)` forbid to backtrack in all the matched content on his left if the subpattern will fail later. `(?!)` forces the subpattern to fail ("not followed by nothing" is always false).

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

Either you are replacing *every* class selector, in which case you use:

`(\.[\w_\-]+)\b` -- example: http://regex101.com/r/kM3dK9

Or you're going to need to specify which ones you're replacing:

`(\.(selector4|selector_5|other6))\b` -- example: http://regex101.com/r/aC6dR3